# How can I set my linux box as a router to forward ip packets?

Tags: networking, ip-forward

I am doing a network experiment about ip packet forwarding, but I don't know why it does work.

I have a linux machine with two network interfaces, eth0 and eth1 both with static IP address (eth0: 192.168.100.1, eth1: 192.168.101.2).

My goal is simple, I just want to forward ip packets from eth1 with destination in subnet 192.168.100.0/24 to eth0, and forward ip packets from eth0 with destination in subnet 192.168.101.0/24 to eth1.

I turned on ip forwarding with:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

my routing table is like this:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway     Genmask        Flags Metric Ref   Use  Iface
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0  U     0      0       0  eth0
192.168.101.0   0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0  U     0      0       0  eth1
```

But, when I try to ping from 192.168.100.25 to 192.168.101.47, it does not work.

Answer (score 26):

You need to add a *forwarding rule* using `iptables` command, something like this:

```
modprobe iptable_nat
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

see `man iptables` for more details, or search internet for howto articles, for example [How to set up a NAT router on a Linux-based computer](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_set_up_a_NAT_router_on_a_Linux-based_computer)

Here is [Linux IP Masquerade HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/) which discusses the topic in details.

You should also ensure that you have no other rules (e.g. in the `FORWARD` chain) that are overriding the above `ACCEPT` rule. If there are, you probably want to delete them.

Comment: I don't know why, but it still don't work. I have added both `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT` and `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT` to my tables. And my INPUT, OUTPUT, and FORWARD policy are all `ACCEPT`.

Comment: There are many things which can be configured wrong. For example, you host's IP should be specified as "gateway IP" on the hosts in the "internal" network, so they know that if an IP is not in the range of their "local" network the packets need to be sent to your gateway machine. This is similar to the usual setup where ADSL router is registered as gateway for hosts in the LAN

Comment: When I use `traceroute` on my host, it shows that the packet goes to the "router" (192.168.100.1), but it don't go any further.

Comment: @UniMouS: Seems that I've forgotten about MASQUERADE thing - I've edited my answer and added new links to articles.

Comment: @Sergey 10 years later and that comment is very true. For me the trouble was not in the device with forwarding, but in the client device. It was the dhcp client service assigning a link local address at some point (even though the interface has a static ip configuration) which in turn messed up the routes somehow. Disabling the dhcp service solved it.

Comment: Missing the following rule: `iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`; this was especially an issue for me perhaps because docker has several rules installed; Ref: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Internet_sharing#Enable_NAT

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a route to both 192.168.100.25 and 192.168.101.47.

If your forwarding server has IPs 192.168.100.1 and 192.168.101.1 you would add in client 192.168.100.25

```
ip route 192.168.101.0/24 via 192.1268.100.1
```

and in client 192.168.101.47

```
ip route 192.168.100.0/24 via 192.168.101.1
```

(This works with just forwarding enabled, no iptables).