# How to route VLAN subnetworks to my DSL ppp0

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, pppoe

I have a fiber optic connection through a Huawei ONT device. (I don't know the exact model) The device mode changed to "modem" by the ISP so I should connect through PPPoE. (I have the username and password)

When I tested with Windows 7 x64 the PPPoE connection worked perfectly.

I have a 16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus) server (no GUI) with 3 ethernet connections:

- eth0 - onboard NIC
- eth1 - onboard NIC
- wan0 - PCI-X NIC

The ONT device is connected to "wan0", and the PPPoE connection configured with "pppoeconf".

"pppoeconf" created a "ppp0" interface. PPP connection has two IP address: on public side there is a fixed public IP (for example FIX.EDI.PAD.DRE.SSS) and on the private side IP address is 10.0.0.1/32.

**From the Linux server terminal I could ping 8.8.8.8, google.com, browse any website with Lynx. And the server allowing SSH connections from the internet.**

So the PPPoE connection works perfectly.

This server is connected to subnetworks through "eth0", "eth1" NIC(s). Subnetworks are logically separated by VLANs (eth0.11, eth1.22, eth1.33, ...)

Here is the "/etc/network/interfaces" file content:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wan0
iface wan0 inet dhcp
     
auto eth0.11
iface eth0.11 inet static
     address 10.1.0.1
     network 10.1.0.0
     netmask 255.255.0.0
     broadcast 10.1.255.255
     vlan-raw-device eth0

auto eth1.22
iface eth1.22 inet static
     address 10.2.0.1
     network 10.2.0.0
     netmask 255.255.0.0
     broadcast 10.2.255.255
     vlan-raw-device eth1

auto eth1.33
iface eth1.33 inet static
     address 10.3.0.1
     network 10.3.0.0
     netmask 255.255.0.0
     broadcast 10.3.255.255
     vlan-raw-device eth1
     
auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /bin/ip link set wan0 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider
```

Last block (`auto dsl-provider ...`) was added by "pppoeconf".

Linux server provides DHCP, DNS, NTP services for subnetworks' machine.

There is a test Windows 7 x64 machine configured to use VLAN 33. This machine get dynamic IP from Linux in the given range. I could ping only in VLAN (33) subnetwork and 10.3.0.1.

**I could NOT ping 8.8.8.8, google.com or anything else from VLAN subnetwork(s), so basically can't reach the internet**

There are some iptables roules (default is DROP), here are some relevant lines:

```
$IPTABLES -N privnet_as_source_accept
$IPTABLES -A privnet_as_source_accept -i eth0.11 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A privnet_as_source_accept -i eth1.22 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A privnet_as_source_accept -i eth1.33 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A privnet_as_source_accept -j DROP

.
.
.

# Allow everything which is related to an earlier action
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# ICMP forward all subtype from private network to internet
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -p icmp -j privnet_as_source_accept

# SSH
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -p tcp --dport 22   -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j privnet_as_source_accept

# whois
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -p udp --dport 43   -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j privnet_as_source_accept
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -p tcp --dport 43   -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j privnet_as_source_accept

# DNS
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -p udp --dport 53   -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j privnet_as_source_accept
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -p tcp --dport 53   -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j privnet_as_source_accept

# HTTP
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -p tcp --dport 80   -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j privnet_as_source_accept
```

Output of `route -vn`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0.111
10.2.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1.222
10.3.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1.333
```

What am I missing? Why I can't reach the internet from client machines in VLAN(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable ip forwarding?

You can check with the following command:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

A returned value of 0 means forwarding is not enabled, while a value of 1 means it is enabled. This can be permanently set in the /etc/sysctl.conf file. ipv4 and ipv6 have separate settings. Use the following command to reload the config file after making changes:

```
# sysctl -p
```

More information available here:
[How can I set my linux box as a router to forward ip packets?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227369/how-can-i-set-my-linux-box-as-a-router-to-forward-ip-packets)

There may also be specific settings introduced with systemd, but I have not confirmed this. See this link for more information: https://serverfault.com/questions/753977/how-to-properly-permanent-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux-with-systemd